# How does control system design ensure correct elevator position with the steering system unlocked?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, airplane, student-pilot, engineering

I’m having some trouble answering the following problem encountered in one of the worksheets for aviation students:

> The plane shown in the picture stands on the runway. The pilot, while getting off, did not lock the steering control system. Nevertheless, the elevator remained horizontal. How can this effect be ensured in a correctly designed control system?

[image]

I'm looking forward to some hints. Thank you in advance

Comment: Two downvotes, three close votes, and zero constructive criticism?!  OK, I'll start:  The pilot "getting off" has a different meaning for most native English speakers, but I will assume you meant securing and leaving the airplane parked after a flight?  That makes some sense from the context of the control locks, but then it wouldn't be on the runway.  Did you mean taking off? Please clarify.  Other than that, there's probably an easy answer for the control surfaces being neutral when stationary that has to do with springs and counterweights, but I don't have the engineering chops to answer...

Comment: @EngineerinProgress sorry the tomatoes are flying on this one.  In the future it may be best to *reference* your source as foundation.  Who published this "worksheet for aviation students", or is it for engineering students?.  Yes, a hanging heavy solid steel control stick might help hold the elevator level, but at rest, with no one in the plane, the elevator is best *pointed down* a bit so a gust doesn't fly the plane off the ground.  In flight, the *trim tab* holds the elevator in place through *aerodynamic forces*.  It is generally not a good idea to hop out of a plane without securing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat dumb question, but here's one take at an answer.

The upside-down control stick with the rigging shown tries to remain vertical by gravity. If a wind gust tries to push the tail down, the fuselage will rotate clockwise and the control stick will then apply a nose-up control force to the elevator and make the nose-up pitching moment worse.

To prevent this, the upside-down control stick has to be rigged in the opposite sense so a clockwise (pitch up) motion of the fuselage will cause the stick to apply a pitch-down control force to the elevator.

Comment: Totally agree with your assessment of the homework question. Who says that a "correctly designed control system" means the elevator is aligned with the horizontal stab when there is neither aerodynamic force nor pressure on the controls???

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this question is about how best to design an aircraft control system so that the elevator remains horizontal when the aircraft is at rest on the ground with no one in the cockpit and no control locks installed. It seems likely that the intended answer would involve a design that didn't involve a "pendulum" effect (as shown in the illustration due to the weight of the "hanging" control stick) acting to hold the elevator in a horizontal position when the fuselage is at rest.  The problem with a "pendulum" design, as noted in another answer to this ASE question, is that it creates a connection between the fuselage pitch attitude *in steady-state flight*, and the trim position of the elevator.  The elevator will tend to trim higher (causing a nose-up control input) when the aircraft is climbing than when it is descending.  This means that adding power will tend to cause the elevator to rise.  This is generally not desirable.

If for some reason it is deemed desirable that the elevator remain horizontal when the aircraft is at rest on the ground with no one at the controls -- and it's debatable whether this a really a characteristic of a "correctly designed control system"-- then a re-design could use a control yoke rather than a control stick, or could use a lightweight control stick mounted in the conventional way, and could use springs to hold the elevator in a horizontal position.  Proper "balancing" of the elevator in relation to the hinge line or pivot point could minimize the amount of spring force needed to accomplish this.

All things considered, it's a very poor homework question.  The use of the word "steering" is objectionable, as is the statement that the plane is "on the runway" (apparently should read "ramp" or "tarmac" or "parking area"),  and rather than specifying a "correctly designed" control system, the question ought to specify what design objectives should be met, that are lacking in the design shown in the diagram.

Comment: +1 for "_it's a very poor homework question_". And since it ***is*** a homework question with no sign of effort from the OP, I'd offer [my general appeal](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4306/7532). Although the assigned question itself is such a mess, this isn't quite the same as a question asking for a computation.